# What is the power of the set of $A :=\{\varnothing , \{\varnothing\}\}$.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

a) How many elements does the set $\{\varnothing, \{\varnothing,\{\varnothing\}\}, \{\{\varnothing\}\}, \{\{\varnothing\},\varnothing,\varnothing\}\}$ have?

b) What is the power of the set of $A :=\{\varnothing, \{\varnothing\}\}$.

For part b) I was thinking that it has $2^2-1$ elements since $\varnothing$ is itself an element.

Comment: For some set S, $|\mathcal P(S)| = 2^{|S|}$, always.

Comment: You don't need to subtract 1. Just write A and B in place of your two elements and you will always get the right answer.

Comment: This may help http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WBdrez3PRwo :D btw, I wonder if we can link to other sites like youtube for reference? Is it against the rules?

Comment: @user49685 As long as it is not violating copyright or something, I think so

Answer (score 1):

**a)** Let's define some symbols. $a = \varnothing,\,b=\{\varnothing,\{\varnothing\}\},\,c=\{\{\varnothing\}\},\,d=\{\{\varnothing\},\varnothing,\varnothing\}\}$. Notice that since a set cannot contain the same element twice, and order does not matter, we can write $d = \{\varnothing,\{\varnothing\}\} = b$. The set in question $A$ is then, $\{a, b, c, d\} = \{a, b, c, b\} = \{a, b, c\}$, and thus $|A| = 3$.

How do we know though that none of $a, b$ and $c$ are equal to each other? Because $|a| = 0,\,|b| = 2,\,|c| = 1$.

**b)** Let's define some symbols again. $a = \varnothing,\,b = \{\varnothing\}$. Then we can write, $\mathcal P(A) = \{\{\}, \{a\}, \{b\}, \{a, b\}\}$. In general, $|\mathcal P(S)| = 2^{|S|}$ for some set $S$.

Comment: True but not very useful, given the implied level of knowledge of the asker.

Comment: I know. There just isn't anything to explain.

Comment: I am sorry but i am not quite sure if there are 4 elements in part a)..would you mind explaining how you got 4 elements. @BenFrankel

Comment: @augurar Actually it's not true.. answer is now corrected and explained.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: If you put a whole set $A$ into another set $B$, $A$ only counts as one element of $B$.